# Pyspark StandardScaler over a Window

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I want to use the standardscaler `pyspark.ml.feature.StandardScaler` over window of my data.

```
df4=spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1,1, 'X', 'a'),
        (2,1, 'X', 'a'),
        (3,9, 'X', 'b'),
        (5,1, 'X', 'b'),
        (6,2, 'X', 'c'),
        (7,2, 'X', 'c'),
        (8,10, 'Y', 'a'),
        (9,45, 'Y', 'a'),
        (10,3, 'Y', 'a'),
        (11,3, 'Y', 'b'),
        (12,6, 'Y', 'b'),
        (13,19,'Y', 'b')
    ],
    ['id','feature', 'txt', 'cat'] 
)

w = Window().partitionBy(..)
```

I can do this over the whole dataframe by calling the `.fit`& `.transform` methods. But not on the `w` variable which we use generally like `F.col('feature') - F.mean('feature').over(w)`.

I can transform all my windowed/grouped data into separate columns, put it into a dataframe and then apply StandardScaler over it and transform back to `1D`. Is there any other method ? The ultimate goal is to try different scalers including `pyspark.ml.feature.RobustScaler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually had to write my own scaler class. Using the `pyspark StandardScaler` in the above problem is not suitable as we all know it is more efficient for end to end series transformations. Nonetheless I came up with my own scaler. It does not really use `Window` from pyspark but i achieve the functionality using `groupby`.

```
class StandardScaler:
    
    tol = 0.000001
    
    def __init__(self, colsTotransform, groupbyCol='txt', orderBycol='id'):
        self.colsTotransform = colsTotransform
        self.groupbyCol=groupbyCol
        self.orderBycol=orderBycol
    
    def __tempNames__(self):
        return [(f"{colname}_transformed",colname) for colname in self.colsTotransform]
    
    def fit(self, df):
        funcs = [(F.mean(name), F.stddev(name)) for name in self.colsTotransform]
        exprs = [ff for tup in funcs for ff in tup]
        self.stats = df.groupBy([self.groupbyCol]).agg(*exprs)
    
    def __transformOne__(self, df_with_stats, newName, colName):
        return df_with_stats\
                .withColumn(newName, 
                            (F.col(colName)-F.col(f'avg({colName})'))/(F.col(f'stddev_samp({colName})')+self.tol))\
                .drop(colName)\
                .withColumnRenamed(newName, colName)

    def transform(self, df):
        df_with_stats = df.join(self.stats, on=self.groupbyCol, how='inner').orderBy(self.orderBycol)
        return reduce(lambda df_with_stats, kv: self.__transformOne__(df_with_stats, *kv), 
                       self.__tempNames__(), df_with_stats)[df.columns]
```

Usage :

```
ss = StandardScaler(colsTotransform=['feature'],groupbyCol='txt',orderbyCol='id')
ss.fit(df4)
ss.stats.show()

+---+------------------+--------------------+
|txt|      avg(feature)|stddev_samp(feature)|
+---+------------------+--------------------+
|  Y|14.333333333333334|  16.169930941926335|
|  X|2.6666666666666665|  3.1411250638372654|
+---+------------------+--------------------+

df4.show()

+---+-------+---+---+
| id|feature|txt|cat|
+---+-------+---+---+
|  1|      1|  X|  a|
|  2|      1|  X|  a|
|  3|      9|  X|  b|
|  5|      1|  X|  b|
|  6|      2|  X|  c|
|  7|      2|  X|  c|
|  8|     10|  Y|  a|
|  9|     45|  Y|  a|
| 10|      3|  Y|  a|
| 11|      3|  Y|  b|
| 12|      6|  Y|  b|
| 13|     19|  Y|  b|
+---+-------+---+---+

ss.transform(df4).show()
+---+--------------------+---+---+
| id|             feature|txt|cat|
+---+--------------------+---+---+
|  1|  -0.530595281053646|  X|  a|
|  2|  -0.530595281053646|  X|  a|
|  3|  2.0162620680038548|  X|  b|
|  5|  -0.530595281053646|  X|  b|
|  6|-0.21223811242145835|  X|  c|
|  7|-0.21223811242145835|  X|  c|
|  8| -0.2679871102053074|  Y|  a|
|  9|  1.8965241645298676|  Y|  a|
| 10| -0.7008893651523425|  Y|  a|
| 11| -0.7008893651523425|  Y|  b|
| 12| -0.5153598273178989|  Y|  b|
| 13|  0.2886015032980233|  Y|  b|
+---+--------------------+---+---+
```